# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.подключаю api twitter в приложении.
Возникла такая проблем:
В один из методов надо передать активити, далее эта активити передается через ряд методов и в конечном счете используется в таком методе

```
Intent newIntent(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);

    return intent;
}
```

но тут вываливается ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName.
Сама активити создается следующим образом

```
new Activity(){
         @Override
          public void startActivityForResult(@RequiresPermission Intent intent, int requestCode) {
             fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
          }


           @Override
           public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
              return fragment.getContext().getPackageManager();
          }};
```

где fragment - фрагмент который передается сверху.
Прошу знающих людей подсказать как устранить данную ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя так создавать `Activity` - тупым вызовом конструктора `Activity` не создается. Создание `Activity` прерогатива операционной системы. Ваша задача описать `Activity`: продекларировать ее в манифесте и реализовать методы типа `onCreate()` и проч.

Comment: угу, уже понял, просто код достался от предыдущего разработчика, и не хотелось нарушать выстроенную архитектуру приложения, но видимо придется....